# Unable to Make POST Request from Django View

Tags: python, django, python-requests

**TL;DR**: I have a POST request (from the Requests module) that works outside of a Django view, but raises an exception of type 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error' inside the view. Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

**The Problem:**

I am using Django 1.7.11, Requests 2.14.2, and Python 2.7.14 to host a web application in Linux on AWS.

The directory structure of the web application is set up like this:

```
myproject
|___myapp
|  |
|  |___templates
|  |   |
|  |   |___mytemplate.html
|  |
|  |___views.py
|  |___urls.py
|
|___post_request.py
```

I have a function in views.py that is being called directly from a link in the Django template, mytemplate.html. The link in the template is not part of a form and is specified like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:myview' %}">The Link to My View</a></li>
```

The corresponding entry in myapp/urls.py is:

```
url(r"^myview/$", the_view_function, name="myview")
```

My function within myapp/views.py looks like this:

```
def the_view_function(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        context = {}
        data = {}
        headers = {}
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Token aaaaabbbbbcccc'
        the_url = "https://www.example.com/rest/endpoint/"

        logger.info("view function called")

        if 'variable_1' in request.session:
            variable_1 = request.session['variable_1']
            logger.info("Variable 1 is set")
        else:
            variable_1 = 0
            logger.info("Variable 1 is zero")

        if 'variable_2' in request.session:
            variable_2 = request.session['variable_2']
        else:
            variable_2 = -1

        if variable_1 == 0:
            logger.info("First time")
            data['first_name'] = 'firstname'
            data['last_name'] = 'lastname'
            data['email'] = 'user@not.valid.email.com'
            data['role'] = "User"

            the_response = requests.post(the_url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

The following line fails:

```
the_response = requests.post(the_url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

When I click 'The Link to My View' from the page in my web browser, the request raises an exception of type 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'.

**However:**

I have the following code in the post_request.py file:

```
import requests

the_url = "https://www.example.com/rest/endpoint/"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token aaaaabbbbbcccc'}
post_data = dict()
post_data['first_name'] = 'firstname'
post_data['last_name'] = 'lastname'
post_data['email'] = 'user@not.valid.email.com'
post_data['role'] = "User"

the_response = requests.post(the_url, headers=headers, data=post_data, verify=False)
print(the_response.status_code)
```

When I run this code from the myproject directory using:

```
python post_request.py
```

I get a 201 response, which is what I should be getting from the view.

Can someone please explain why the POST request works when not running as part of the Django view, but fails from inside the view? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You haven't really given enough information here. Where is the rest of that view? What is `the_url`? Is it pointing to an external site, or back to the same Django site?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The url points to an external site; it's a REST endpoint from an API we use in other projects many times a day. Adding the function from the view.